# how to add my angular app in another simple web pages?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, iframe

I want to integrate my angular app in many others simple web pages, but without iframe

In the next code we see a simple and external html web page called "Shoes Store".

"Shoes Store" is a web that sells shoes. And my goal is in `<div id="my-angular-app"></div>`  to add my entire my-angular-app in that `div`.

As you can see, first, we need a async petition for then instantiate in a varible the my-angular-app.

The goal is to do something like next html. See how my-angular-app is called async

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!--external web page-->
    <title>Shoes Store</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="my-angular-app"></div>

    <script async src="http://localhost:4201/my-angular-app.min.js?secret=abcdfg"></script>
     
    // see how myAngularApp is instanciated (many times as you want)
    <script>
        myAngularApp = new MyAngularApp(document.getElementById('my-angular-app'), {
            someParams: {x: 'x', y: 'y'},
            otherParams: 1
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I want implement the same architecture of google maps api, but with my angular app.

Imagine that you are the owner of google-maps and no are implementations yet, and the goal is implement the same way as nowsdays works, but with a angular-app.

the result will most something like this:

[see this diagram](https://i.ibb.co/QkzxFvg/20210408-170712.png)

page1, page2, page3 can integrate to my-angular-app and they can instantiate all entire app, many times using javascript, instead iframe tag

Please, the next implementations are inviables:

- No iframe
- No angular elements
- No Webpack 5 Module federation

someone have an example to integrate this ?
very much apreciated

Comment: Why no angular elements?

Comment: @Thomas I think that it's not a single component but whole app with for example routing. The way here could be adding other apps to the `angular.json` with same `rootDir` but different `outputDir`. But I am not sure if it's even possible.

Comment: Angular elements is the way to go. Routing will work if you use hash routing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently Angular is not terribly well fitted for that use case. But you can build an angular element and bundle the required other dependencies.
The "element" represents the application root element, but you can have additional compenents, even routing, down the component tree as usual. (You have a root element in every angular app, as well.)

Here is an example repository that shows how to build and embed the element: https://github.com/trion-development/corona-covid19-simulator

The interesting part is the concatenation of all dependencies in https://github.com/trion-development/corona-covid19-simulator/blob/master/package.json#L12